# Parse multiple JSON columns to tables

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with 30 columns, some of them are JSON arrays, and right now I was doing the parsing manually, but I was thinking if there was a dynamic way to do it.

The table is like

```
| flight.atfcmMeasureLocations.item | flight.ctfmAirspaceProfile | flight.ctfmPointProfile |   |   |
|-----------------------------------|----------------------------|-------------------------|---|---|
| null                              | [{...}]                    | []                      |   |   |
| null                              | []                         | [{...},{...}]           |   |   |
| [{...},{...}]                     | [{...}]                    | [{...}, {...}]          |   |   |
```

Right now I'm parsing it like this, but I think is too tedious, and it has to be a way to automatize this process.

```
SELECT field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmMcdmOnlyLocation'                                                                as flightAtfcmMcdmOnlyLocation,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'hotspotId'                                              as flightAtfcmRegulationLocation_hotspotId,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'mcdmState'                                              as flightAtfcmRegulationLocation_mcdmState,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'measureSubType'                                         as flightAtfcmRegulationLocation_measureSubType,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAerodrome'            as flightAtfcmRegulationLocation_referenceLocationReferenceLocationAerodrome,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAerodromeSet'         as flightAtfcmRegulationLocation_referenceLocationReferenceLocationAerodromeSet,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAirspace' ->> 'id'   as flightAtfcmRegulationLocation_referenceLocationReferenceLocationAirspace_id,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAirspace' ->> 'type' as flightAtfcmRegulationLocation_referenceLocationReferenceLocationAirspace_type,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationDBEPoint'            as FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation_referenceLocationReferenceLocationDBEPoint,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationPublishedPoint'      as FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation_referenceLocationReferenceLocationPublishedPoint,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'regulationId'                                           as FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation_regulationId,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation' ->> 'toConfirm'                                              as FlightAtfcmRegulationLocation_toConfirm,
       field::jsonb -> 'FlightAtfcmReroutingLocation'                                                               as FlightAtfcmReroutingLocation

FROM (Select json_array_elements(case
                                     when ("flight.atfcmMeasureLocations.item"::text = '[]' OR
                                           "flight.atfcmMeasureLocations.item"::text = 'null') then '[null]'::json
                                     else "flight.atfcmMeasureLocations.item" end) field
      from eurocontrol_data) as json;

SELECT field::jsonb -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAerodrome'           as referenceLocationReferenceLocationAerodrome,
       field::jsonb -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAerodromeSet'        as referenceLocationReferenceLocationAerodromeSet,
       field::jsonb -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAirspace' ->> 'id'   as referenceLocationReferenceLocationAirspace_id,
       field::jsonb -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationAirspace' ->> 'type' as referenceLocationReferenceLocationAirspace_type,

       field::jsonb -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationDBEPoint'            as referenceLocationReferenceLocationDBEPoint,
       field::jsonb -> 'referenceLocation-ReferenceLocationPublishedPoint'      as referenceLocationReferenceLocationPublishedPoint,
       field::jsonb -> 'regulationId'                                           as regulationId,
       field::jsonb -> 'toConfirm'                                              as toConfirm

FROM (Select json_array_elements(case
                                     when "flight.regulationLocations"::text = '[]' then '[null]'::json
                                     else "flight.regulationLocations" end) field
      from eurocontrol_data) as json;
```

My main goal is to parse the json to tables, and have some relation between the old cells and the new tables to have a relation between a master table and the new tables, maybe with indexes and it will be similar to this:

```
| flight.atfcmMeasureLocations.item | flight.ctfmAirspaceProfile | flight.ctfmPointProfile |   |   |
|-----------------------------------|----------------------------|-------------------------|---|---|
| null                              | 1                          | []                      |   |   |
| null                              | []                         | 1                       |   |   |
| 1                                 | 2                          | 2                       |   |   |
```

Although to be honest, I'm a newbie so not sure how is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem, and decided to write a python library to do the job automatically. Here is the link to the library: https://github.com/zolekode/json-to-tables .

For completeness, let me copy the example from the readme here:

Assume this is your JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "truck",
        "brand": "BMW",
        "num_wheels": 4,
        "engine": {
            "brand": "RR",
            "date_of_production": {
                "day": 3,
                "month": "Feb",
                "year": 1990
            },
            "creators": ["Sandy", "Leslie", "Kane"]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "bike",
        "num_wheels": 2,
        "top_speed": "100Km/hr",
        "engine": {
            "brand": "Audi",
            "date_of_production": {
                "day": 2,
                "month": "Sep",
                "year": 2002
            },
            "creators": ["Anabel", {"GreenMotors": {"CEO": "Charles Green"}}]
        }
    },
]
```

1. First, you load the JSON string.
   `automobiles = json.loads(automobiles)`
2. Then run the following code:

```
extent_table = ExtentTable()
table_maker = TableMaker(extent_table) 
root_table_name = "automobiles" # could use any other name
table_maker.convert_json_objects_to_tables(automobiles, root_table_name)
table_maker.show_tables(num_elements=5)
```

3. Export or visualise your results:

```
SHOWING TABLES :D


automobiles
   ID   name brand num_wheels engine top_speed
0   0  truck   BMW          4      0      None
1   1   bike  None          2      1  100Km/hr
2   2   None  None       None   None      None
____________________________________________________

engine
   ID brand date_of_production
0   0    RR                  0
1   1  Audi                  1
2   2  None               None
____________________________________________________

date_of_production
   ID   day month  year
0   0     3   Feb  1990
1   1     2   Sep  2002
2   2  None  None  None
____________________________________________________

engine_?_creators
  ID PARENT_ID is_scalar  scalar
0  0         0      True   Sandy
1  1         0      True  Leslie
2  2         0      True    Kane
3  3         1      True  Anabel
4  4         1     False    None
____________________________________________________

GreenMotors
   ID            CEO
0   0  Charles Green
1   1           None
____________________________________________________


engine_?_creators_$_GreenMotors
   ID GreenMotors PARENT_ID
0   0           0         4
1   1        None      None
____________________________________________________
```

Tip: try to keep attribute names as unique as possible. This solution worked for my projects. If you find any bugs or have any ideas on how to improve it, you could create a pull request. A last row with Empty/None values is sometimes created when the script is done (apart from the ID, every other value is None or an empty string). You should not use those rows. They are there out of convenience to ease processing.

A complete example is found here: https://github.com/zolekode/json-to-tables/blob/master/example.py.